# Passbook, show beacon relevantText, not location relevantText

Tags: iphone, passbook, ibeacon

I have a Passbook (for an airline boarding pass). I want to have a relevantText based on either the location or an iBeacon. Specifically, I want that as the user enters the airport she gets the "you're in airport" message on lock screen, and as she goes to a specific part of the airport with a beacon, she gets the more specific "you're in the airport cafe" message.

From what I can figure out, if you have a location & beacon defined in the passbook, the user will never see the beacon message (assuming these geographically overlap).

**So, my question is, is there any way to tell Passbook that beacon takes priority over location for determine the lockscreen message?**

Below is a snippet of my passbook.

```
"beacons" : [
   {
    "proximityUUID":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "major":1,
    "minor":2,
    "relevantText":"Welcome to the airport cafe"
   }
],
"locations" : [
  { 
    "latitude" : [airport latitude],
    "longitude" : [airport longitude],
    "relevantText":"You're in the airport"
  } 
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a number of tests on a Pass with both location & beacon alerts at the same location.
It seems that (for me at least) the location alerts always took priority over the beacon alerts .. unfortunately the opposite of what you want (and the opposite of how it probably should be!) ..

Probably need to make an enhancement-request on Bugreporter.
Apple responds faster to any radar that has multiple-duplicates .. so if you make such a request, please post the ID number here (and on devforms.apple.com) so that others (including me) can create a duplicate ..

One workaround: you can use the maxDistance parameter for location alerts to reduce the radius of the 'You're in the airport' location alert - set it to go off at the terminal entrance but not cover the same area as the beacon ..

Comment: BTW - I also tried the maxDistance approach, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Passbook is pretty coarse-grained in what it allows you to do.

If you have your own iOS app anyway and want a higher level of control, you could roll your own local notifications triggered by CoreLocation APIs that emulate Passbook behavior.  Clearly this is more work, and wouldn't be viable if you are using Passbook without a custom app.

If you decide to take that approach, you could easily make entering a CLBeaconRegion (for an iBeacon) take priority over what gets displayed to the user based on entering a regular CLRegion (for a Geofence).  My company offers a service called [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.com) that makes managing these regions server-side easy, but you could take this approach with or without that service.